# Check if the context is the same as class in intent call

Tags: android, android-intent

Currently i have a method that calls an activity:

```
  public void startActivity(final Context context, final Class mClass){

                    Intent i = new Intent(context, mClass);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
```

i need to know if my context and my  class are the same. is that possible?
i need to do that because i don't want to call a same activity if i'm already in that activity(context).

here is my sample implementation on how i'm currently using the method:

```
  @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            // set item as selected to persist highlight
            //     item.setChecked(false);
            // close drawer when item is tapped
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers()
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.drawer_home:
                    startActivity(mContext,MainActivity.class);
                    break;
                case R.id.drawer_pay:
                    startActivity(mContext,BillsPaymentActivity.class);
                    break;
                case R.id.drawer_load:
                    startActivity(mContext,BuyAndSellLoadActivity.class);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: You SHOULD consider to rename your function, because a method `startActivity` already exists.

Comment: @Procra uhm. That confueses me a lot. i'm sorry?

Comment: if you type `startActivity` anywhere in an Activity or a Fragment the autofill will suggest you a method `startActivity()`that takes an intent and opens the class given to this intent. You're actually using it in your custom method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method `getClass()` to get the class of context and compare it with your class.

```
if(!context.getClass().equals(mClass)) {
    // start activity.
}
```

Comment: There is no context.getClass().equals :(

Comment: The method `getClass()` and `equals()` exists in all classes. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Try **instanceof** to compare object with specific class type, in your case :

```
if(!(mContext instanceof MainActivity)) {
    // This means context is not of MainActivity
}
```